# Tag number to Name string

Tags: python, quickfix

In QuickFix, how can I get the name of the tag from the tag number using Python? For example, for OrdStatus, how do I convert tag number 5 to the String "OrdStatus_CANCELED"?

Comment: Which version of QuickFIX are you using? QuickFIX/N? QuickFIX/J? C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**.NET:**

If you are using QuickFIX/N, you can achieve this using a `DataDictionary` instance with whatever data source you want (e.g., FIX42.xml). Note that you can get the `DataDictionary` instance associated with a given `Session` or the application itself with `Session`'s properties `SessionDataDictionary` and `ApplicationDataDictionary`, respectively.

Consider this trivial C# program:

```
namespace QuickFixTests
{
    using System;

    using QuickFix;
    using QuickFix.DataDictionary;
    using QuickFix.Fields;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var qfm = new Message();
            qfm.SetField(new OrdStatus('4'));
            var ordStatus = qfm.GetField(Tags.OrdStatus);
            var dd = new DataDictionary("FIX42.xml");
            Console.WriteLine(dd.FieldsByTag[39].EnumDict[ordStatus]); // Prints CANCELED
        }
    }
}
```

**C++/Python:**

The C++ `DataDictionary` class has a method [`getValueName`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/370cb3eaf01da5fa09af26467342a908cd32e251/src/C%2B%2B/DataDictionary.h#L130):

```
bool getValueName( int field, const std::string& value, std::string& name ) const
{
  ValueToName::const_iterator i = m_valueNames.find( std::make_pair(field, value) );
  if(i == m_valueNames.end()) return false;
  name = i->second;
  return true;
}
```

The following snippets (with comments added) from one of the [Python DataDictionary unit tests](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/e5216dcd1f30a2741de6fe46207af18a091e39a8/src/python/test/DataDictionaryTestCase.py#L117) show how to use `getValueName` given a `DataDictionary` instance.

```
# Create a DataDictionary
def setUp(self):
    self.object = fix.DataDictionary()

# Add a dummy value
self.object.addValueName( 23, "BOO", "VALUE_23_BOO" )

# Test that the dummy value's name in the dictionary matches what was set
self.assertEquals( "VALUE_23_BOO", self.object.getValueName(23, "BOO", "")
```

Comment: Can you also provide an example using Python? Thanks!

Comment: Updated with a Python example.